# If square root is the inverse function of $5^2$ what is the inverse function of $5^1$

Tags: roots

I am not great at maths or anything, but just had a general question:

If square root is the opposite of $5^2$, what is the opposite of $5^1$, $5^3$, $5^4$?

Is there an opposite? How would I work it out?

I may be having a brain freeze but thank you for your help.

Comment: What is an opposite of a number like $5^2$?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation#Rational_exponents

Comment: You mean $x^n\leftrightarrow x^{1/n}$? That's how roots work.

Answer (score 4):

I think you mean *inverse* rather than *opposite*. The *inverse* of **square** is **squareroot** which could be expressed as:$$f(x)=x^2$$$$\therefore f^{-1}(x)=\sqrt{x}=x^{\frac{1}{2}}$$In a similar vein the inverse of cubing a number would be expressed as:$$f(x)=x^3$$$$\therefore f^{-1}(x)=\sqrt[3]{x}=x^{\frac{1}{3}}$$And in general:$$f(x)=x^n$$$$\therefore f^{-1}(x)=x^{\frac{1}{n}}$$
**NOTE:** When $n=1$ you get a function that is its own inverse, i.e.:$$f(x)=x$$$$\therefore f^{-1}(x)=x$$This is called the **identity function**.

Comment: thank you for your reply, yes I meant inverse function!

Comment: Note that the inverse of $x^1$ is just $x^1$ again!

Answer (score 1):

The inverse of the map $x\mapsto x^d$ is $x\mapsto x^{1/d}$ for $d\in\mathbf{R}_{+}^{\star}$. By opposite I guess you mean the inverse function, right ?

Comment: thank you for your reply, yes I meant inverse function!